# Odoo 10 stock transfer under wrong company

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, odoo

### The Scenario

I am running Odoo 10 Community on a postgresql 9.4 database.  I have multiple companies setup, including a parent company and two child companies.  A PO was setup incorrectly in the parent company; it should have been done in one of the child companies.  As a result, inventory is incorrect.  The items received under the errant PO are showing up in the parent's stock, when the parent should have no stock.

### How I pooched things up a bit

In an effort to move the stock over to the correct company, I ran the following query:

```
UPDATE purchase_order
  SET company_id = 5
  WHERE name = 'PO00003';
UPDATE purchase_order_line
  SET company_id = 5
  WHERE order_id = 
    (SELECT id FROM purchase_order WHERE name = 'PO00003');
UPDATE stock_move
  SET (company_id, location_id, location_destination_id) = (5, 22, 22)
  WHERE source_document = 'PO00003';
UPDATE stock_quant
  SET (company_id, location_id) = (5, 22)
  WHERE (product_id, location_id) IN((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 1);
```

Where the child `company_id` is `5`, desired `location_id` is `22`, and the PO in question is `PO00003`.

I may have run other queries as well, but cannot recall what they are, as I lost them in a spontaneous pgAdmin reset.

After running the queries, I ran basic `SELECT` queries to verify the changes took place.

### The current "pooched" behaviour

This created some strange behaviour on the front-end.  The stock transfer now shows up in both the parent and child companies, though the inventory is still showing as being at the parent.  When reviewing all the various documents such as the PO and the transfer records from the parent company, all company fields show the child company.  However, when I attempt to view the same transfer document when logged under the child company, I receive the following warning:
[image: Odoo Warning - Access Error]

Clicking ok brings up the a blank version of the transfer document; no items listed.

### Where to go from here?

I have been trying to figure out which tables I may have missed in my queries.  Digging around the Odoo community forums reveals not a whole lot of information.  So, I am hoping to find some help in locating which other records need to be addressed in order to complete my transfer of the PO and subsequent stock moves from the parent company to the child company.

Comment: Are you the administrator? If not, should you just contact the admin and let them sort it out without further chance of more pooching?

Comment: Yes, I am the administrator.  I've been running my queries on a duplicate database to get things straightened out before applying the fix to the live environment.